# Copy the content of a Sharepoint Folder to a Blob Container using Data Factory

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, azure-data-factory

The requirement is to copy the PDF files from these folders and subfolders to a blob container. The files should be placed in the blob container without retaining the folder structure, only the files themselves... I have the following pipeline which looks like this:

[image]

This pipeline successfully fetches only one file within the SharePoint folder location. The URL from the "Get Metadata" activity looks like this:

> https://cactuscompany.sharepoint.com/sites/cactuscompany/_api/web/GetFolderByServerRelativeUrl('/sites/mydatateam/Shared
> Documents/General/Global/the_data_I_need/')/Files

The dataset looks like this:

[image]

And this is also what I have as part of the dataset properties in my copy activity:

```
@concat(replace(activity('get metadata').output.value[0]['odata.id'],'https://cactuscompany.sharepoint.com/',''),'/$value')
```

[image]

What am I missing? What can I do to make my pipeline fetch the rest of the files in this SharePoint location and also go and get those files in the subfolders?

Answer (score 0):

To copy the files from the subfolders, use combination of logic apps and ADF pipeline.

Use **Sharepoint connector - Get items** action in logic apps to get all file paths list from subfolders. Add the parameter **Include Nested Items** in this.

This will give all the files list but it also includes the meta data properties of folders as well. To filter these out, use **Filter array** in logic app and check for `{IsFolder}` value `False` like below.

value - `@body('Get_items')?['value']` and `@item()?['{IsFolder}']` is equal to `@False`.

[image]

Then, the result array from this will only consists of the file properties.

Now, call the ADF from this logic app and pass this array as parameter.

First create an array parameter in ADF pipeline and don't give any default value.

[image]

Publish the pipeline and it will reflect in the logic apps like below. Now, pass the array like this.

```
{
"arr":@{body('Filter_array')}
}
```

[image]

For sample, I have stored the pipeline value in an array variable in the pipeline and it will give the array like this when triggered from logic app.

[image]

Pass this array to a **For-Each in pipeline in sequential** and use copy activity to copy each file to its target. **You need to use parameterized linked service** for the source and pass the `@item()['{FullPath}']` in the relative URL. Use the Bearer token and the files will copied after the for-loop.